# How to animate sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm using this script for sorting:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

My code looks something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/jeZDB/

Do you have any ideas on how could I implement an animation during sorting?

Comment: I use this plugin: http://mitya.co.uk/scripts/Animated-table-sort-REGEXP-friendly-111

Comment: I think you'd have to be more specific as to what sort of animation you want to happen. Should the animation follow the algorithm or should it just move all the elements into the correct position at the same time?

Comment: at the same time, like in asawayer's examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're using jQuery, but you might want to check this plugin: 
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 2):

Because the algorithm internally makes use of `node.insertBefore(...)` the sorting can't be animated this way.
If you want to solve this on your own my first attempt would be 1.) precalculate the position of each element when sorted and then 2.) animate each element to that position.
But the proposed plugins also look nice.